# Unified IDs of geographical locations

Tags: location, geospatial

I want to use locations' titles in my app, like 'Chicago, Illinois, USA', or 'Surrey, British Columbia, Canada', or one of Springfields.

I am going to add them to the DB one by one during the app lifecycle, no need to add all at once, and think that it would be nice to identify them all with unique IDs. I could just go from `1` to `n`, as a key.

But for future potential flexibility I could use some criteria to make sure I will get that very Springfield when I decode and enter its ID somewhere, like Google.

May be I can use lat/lon data from public sources, e.g. Wikipedia and turn the pair into a key? Or may be there are already some IDs assigned by authorities or some agency that are kind of a standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use a [GeoHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) of the location. This would give you a unique code for each well positioned location you are using. An added bonus is that it would allow you to determine how close they were to each other too.